# Problema al capturar una excepcion en PHP

Tags: php, backend

estoy haciendo un ejercicio en clase de realizar una ecuación de segundo grado y que en el caso de que introduzca texto, me sale una excepcion, el problema es que no me entra en el bloque de catch, directamente me salta los mensajes de warning con la excepción que he creado. Introduzco números el programa me funciona perfectamente, el problema es cuando fuerzo el error introduciendo texto, no se si se me está escapando algún detalle. Os comparto el código y los resultados que me salen.

CODIGO:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 6</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Ejercicio 6</h1>
    <p>Escribe un script para resolver ecuaciones de segundo grado, 
    ax<sup>2</sup> + bx + c = 0. Si la ecuación no tiene soluciones reales,
    hay que mostrar un mensaje de error.</p>

    <!-- Recojo los datos a través de un formulario -->
    <form method="post">
        <label for="ax2">Introduce el valor de ax<sup>2</sup>: </label>
        <input type="text" name="ax2">
        <br><br>
        <label for="bx">Introduce el valor de bx: </label>
        <input type="text" name="bx">
        <br><br>
        <label for="c">Introduce el valor de c: </label>
        <input type="text" name="c">
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calcular" name="calculate">
    </form>
    
</body>
<?php

    //Obtengo los datos del formulario

    //compruebo si se ha pulsado el boton para realizar el cálculo
    if(isset($_POST["calculate"])){

        //almaceno en las variables el valor de los inputs
        $a = $_POST["ax2"];
        $b = $_POST["bx"];
        $c = $_POST["c"];

        if(!is_numeric($a) &&!is_numeric($b) && !is_numeric($c)){ //compruebo que no se introduzca texto
            throw new Exception ("No se permiten números negativos");
        }

        try{ //bloque try para en caso de que se introduzca texto salte la excepcion

            $raiz = sqrt(pow($b,2) - 4 *($a * $c)); //valor de la raiz cuadrada
            $denominador = 2*$a;

            if($raiz > 0){ //en caso de que la raiz sea mayor que 0, tendrá dos solucione la ecuacion

                $numeradorPos = -$b + $raiz; //numerador positivo
                $numeradorNeg = -$b - $raiz; //numerador negativo

                $resultado1 = $numeradorPos / $denominador;
                $resultado2 = $numeradorNeg / $denominador;

                    //muestro los resultado
                    echo "La ecuación tiene dos soluciones: <br>";
                    echo "La primera solución es: $resultado1 <br>";
                    echo "La segunda solución es: $resultado2 <br>";

            }else if($raiz == 0){ //en caso de que la raiz sea igual a 0, la ecuación tendrá una solución

                $numeradorPos = -$b + $raiz; //numerador positivo
                $resultado1 = $numeradorPos / $denominador;

                    //muestro resultados
                    echo "La ecuación tiene una solucion: <br>";
                    echo "La solución es: $resultado1 <br>";

            }else{ //en caso de que la raiz sea menor que 0
                echo "La ecuación no tiene solución";
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){ // en caso de que detecto una excepcion salta el bloque catch
            echo "Excepcion: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
</html>
```

RESULTADOS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la solución que me sale cuando introduzco texto en los inputs

Comment: Intenta tirar la excepcion dentro del `try`

Comment: @alanfcm exactamente era eso, pero no entiendo el porque fallaba eso. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Fallaba porque tú mismo lanzabas una excepción sin controlar...

Comment: De todos modos, si pones las validaciones y los cálculos dentro de una función tendrías el código mejor organizado. Revisa los ejemplos del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php).